# Can't insert duplicate row in vercel postgres using server action

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm using next 14, the project is hosted on vercel. With the simple form bellow : when I click on the button it insert a row in the table.

The issue is that when I click several time on the button validate the row is only inserted in the DB once. Even if I reload the page or restart the app.

If I update the value in the query then when I click on the button a new row is inserted.

When I try to insert the row directly using sql from the vercel console then it works, so the issue seems to be with he server action.

The table

```sql
CREATE table DUMB_TABLE (
        id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

The form

```
      <form action={createDumbTitle}>
        <button type="submit">Validate</button>
      </form>
```

The server action

```
export async function createDumbTitle() {
  await sql<{ title: string }>`
        INSERT INTO DUMB_TABLE (title) VALUES ('dumb_title');
    `;
}
```

EDIT : so it seems it's because the query is cached, because if I change the query like this `INSERT INTO DUMB_TABLE (title) VALUES  ('dumb_title') RETURNING title` then it inesrt the row again, it do it only once then the query get cached again.